# SQLITE column on a LEFT JOIN not populating

Tags: sql, sqlite

So I have a Table called Users which contains a ClassID.
I also have a table called Class which has a ClassID and ClassName.

I am trying to write a query which will bolt the ClassName onto the end of the Users Table.

I am getting all the columns as expected and all cells are populated except for the ClassName. What do I need to do to get the ClassName cells to populate with the name that corresponds with the ID?

This is my query:

```
SELECT Users.UserID, Users.FirstName, Users.Surname, Users.Username, Users.UserType, Users.StudentID, Users.DOB, Users.ClassID, Class.ClassName
from Users LEFT JOIN
     Class
     on Users.ClassID = Class.ClassID
where UserType = 'Student'
order by Users.ClassID;
```

Comment: Your query is fine.  The `ClassId`s don't seem to match.

Comment: I'm not sure why as the Users where assign the ClassIDs based on the Classes available in the Class Table.

On a SELECT * from Class; I can see 2 rows with the ClassIDs 1 and 2.
In my query above it returns 2 users, 1 with ClassID of 1 and another with ClassID of 2.

Comment: Are you sure there are no trailing white spaces in any of the classID columns from either of the tables? That could cause the values to look the same while in reality they’re not